# Return the last non-zero value in a panda df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
    col0 col1   col2 col3 col4
0   1   3   6  6  0
1   0   2   8  7  3
2   0   0   4  3  4
3   4   2   2  0  4
```

The logic is if col1 is not zero, return col1. If col 1 is zero, return col2 (non-zero). If col 2 is zero, return col3. We don't need to do anything for col4

My code looks like below but it only returns col1

```
def test(df):
        if df['col1'].iloc[0] > 0:
            return df['col1']
        elif df['col1'].iloc[0] == 0 & df['col2'].iloc[0] > 0:
            return df['col2']
        elif df['col2'].iloc[0]  == 0 & df['col3'].iloc[0]  > 0:
            return df['col3']
        else:
            return 0
test(new)
```

I tried .any() and .all(), it doesnt work either. Also, is there anyway to make this piece of code more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation on @ALollz idea, since [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html#pandas.DataFrame.lookup) is deprecated on pandas 1.2.0:

```
indices = np.argmax(df.ne(0).values, axis=1)
print(df.values[np.arange(len(df)), indices])
```

**Output**

```
[1 2 4 4]
```

**UPDATE**

For excluding the last column, and return 0, do this instead:

```
indices = np.argmax(df.ne(0).iloc[:, :-1].values, axis=1)
result = np.where(df.ne(0).iloc[:, :-1].any(1), df.values[np.arange(len(df)), indices], 0)
print(result)
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, this should have a column 4 which we don't use. In this case, the len(df) might not work. Is there any other way to solve this. I updated the question

Comment: @codelearner0504 I don't understand, len(df) gives you the number of rows. This works for the new input as well